# How do I restrict the length of character in XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have not dabbled in xml much and have been trying to google my way out of a little of trying to restrict the maximum of characters a user is allowed to enter into a box.

Here is my current code:

```
    <xs:complexType name="reason">
      <xs:attribute name="reason">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value = "75"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>
```

The field name on our database is called reason and I have defined the character length to nvarchar(75).

I am also trying to use same name as the attribute name on the xml.

What is happening currently is that when a user enters more than 75 characters, an error message ensues.

This tells me that the restrictions on my xsd file is not working correctly.

Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: Normally, an xsd type would be used by an instance of something, e.g. an element, like so:`<xs:element name="foo"><xs:complexType><xs:attribute name="reason">...</xs:atttribute></xs:complexType></xs:element>`, which would require that the attribute `reason` of element `foo` was no more than 75 chars in length. We would need to know more about your framework to know how table fields need to be defined?

Comment: Why would you impose a length limit of 75 characters and then be surprised that an error would occur when the user enters more than 75 characters?  And why would you not specify the error message and  the part of your tool chain that produces it?

Comment: @kjhughes, In a regular HTML, you can restrict character limits with maxLength and there would be no errors. If a user uses up all 75 characters, then the user is not allowed to continue but no errors. Not real sure why you are asking this? The reason an error is occuring is because my restriction in the XML schema is not working which is why I came here for assistance.

Comment: Be aware that while an XSD defines validity for an XML document, it does not impose constraints on processing software.  As Stuart has already mentioned, you've neglected to tell us anything about the libraries, tools, or subsystems that are using your XML file.  Until you do so, your question is incomplete, and we cannot help you.

Comment: You seem to be missing the notation that XSD does not define a user interface for your XML.  Your XSD seems to be working as specified.  If you want the user interface to restrict the user's ability to enter more than 75 characters, then you need to find out how to tell your user interface software to enforce the XSD constraints (as in XForms) or to enforce a 75-character length for the field.

Answer (score 2):

**As far as *XML and XSD* are concerned, the answer to your question,**

> How do I restrict the length of character in XML Schema?

**is that this XML, with its `reason/@reason` length no longer than 75 characters,**

```
<reason reason="No more than 75 characters."/>
```

**Will be valid against this XSD:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           version="1.0">

  <xs:element name="reason" type="reason"/>

  <xs:complexType name="reason">
    <xs:attribute name="reason">
      <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:maxLength value = "75"/>
        </xs:restriction>
      </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

### Notes:

1. You're on the right track in your XSD definition.
2. *"I am also trying to use same name as the attribute name on the xml."*  Please do not really name your attributes, elements, and types the same. 
   You can, but it's bad style.
3. As noted in the comments to your question, how violations of the
   length constraint are handled, if at all, depends on the software
   processing the XML.  It appears that you'd like the software to enforce
   the constraints of the XSD ahead of attempting to load it into your
   database.  This is reasonable expectation but not one you can take for granted.